# If condition in postgres function

Tags: database, postgresql, if-statement

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.feerange (txamount decimal,amount decimal,latefeemax decimal)
    RETURNS INTEGER $feerange$
    DECLARE total INTEGER;
    DECLARE amountsum DECIMAL;
    BEGIN
    
    amountsum= amount + latefeemax;
    if txamount <= amountsum AND txamount >= amount
        THEN total=1
        else
           total=0
     RETURN total
    
    END; 
    $feerange $ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

while creating this function I'm getting an error of if condition

but I don't think there anything wrong.

the error is I'm getting is

> /* ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if" LINE 1: if txamount <=
> amountsum AND txamount >= amount

What is wrong with this? Help me to do this!
Thank you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could greatly simplify that as

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.feerange (
   txamount decimal,
   amount decimal,
   latefeemax decimal
) RETURNS integer
   LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT CAST (txamount <= amount + latefeemax AND txamount >= amount AS integer)';
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `end if;` and `;` in few places

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION public.feerange (txamount decimal,amount decimal,latefeemax decimal)
    RETURNS INTEGER
as
$$
    DECLARE total INTEGER;
    DECLARE amountsum DECIMAL;
BEGIN
    amountsum:= amount + latefeemax;
    if txamount <= amountsum AND txamount >= amount
        THEN total:=1;
        else
           total = 0;
    end if;
    RETURN total;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```